# Assign Tags from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, azure

I'm trying to update tags to a list of vm's in a csv file. The csv also contains the resourcegroups.

I can get PowerShell to read the csv, but when I try to assign the tags in the foreach-object it prompts for `Process[0]`

```
Import-Csv c:\temp\vm.csv -Header VMName,ResourceGroup
ForEach-Object {
   $tags = (Get-AzureRMVM -Name $_.VMName -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup).Tags
   $tags['ShutdownSchedule'] = "19:00->06:00,Saturday,Sunday,December 25,December 26,December 27,December 28,December 29,January 1"
   $UpdateTag = Set-AzureRmResource -Tag $tags -Name $_.vmName -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
}
```

Can't see where I'm going wrong. Help :)

Comment: we don't have Azure installed here nor this csv file

Comment: @derloopkat Thanks, just wanted to check the script, is there anything obvious in the scripting.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this powershell script to update tags:

```
$c = Import-csv  "D:\adtest\vm.csv" -header vmname, resourcegroup
foreach($a in $c){
$tags = (get-azurermvm -resourcegroupname $a.resourcegroup -name $a.vmname).tags
$tags['test1'] = "19:00->06:00,Saturday,Sunday,December 25,December 26,December 27,December 28,December 29,January 1"
$UpdateTag = Set-AzureRmResource -Tag $tags -Name $a.vmname -ResourceGroupName $a.resourcegroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines -force
}
```

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> but when I try to assign the tags in the foreach-object it prompts for Process[0]

If I don't want to prompt dialog to confirm update action, you could use the command with `- force`

```
$UpdateTag = Set-AzureRmResource -Tag $tags -Name $line.vmName -ResourceGroupName $line.ResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines -Force
```

I also do a demo for this, it works correctly on my side.

```
$csv = Import-Csv c:\temp\vm.csv -Header VMName,ResourceGroup
foreach($line in $csv)
{ 

   $tags = (Get-AzureRMVM -Name $line.VMName -ResourceGroupName $line.ResourceGroup).Tags
   $tags['ShutdownSchedule'] = "19:00->06:00,Saturday,Sunday,December 25,December 26,December 27,December 28,December 29,January 1" 
   $UpdateTag = Set-AzureRmResource -Tag $tags -Name $line.vmName -ResourceGroupName $line.ResourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines -Force

}
```

**Note:** I use the csv file without header

CSV file format:

```
tomtestvm, tomGroup

xxxxVm, xxxGroup
```